# Calling `Arc::new()` Inside a Rayon Thread Results in Garbage Compiler Errors

Tags: multithreading, rust, channel, reference-counting, rayon

I'm have a function that generates hashes from various inputs. One such hash I want to store as a `Arc<[u8; 16]>` so I can share it between threads and structs. Before, I was storing it as a `Vec<u8>`, passing it over channels and then converting it to `[u8; 16]` locally. Obviously inefficent, hence the `Arc<[u8; 16]>`. But when I made the converstion I got errors like this:

```
error[E0277]: `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Header<'a, Body<'a>>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/lib.rs:182:13
    |
182 |             spawn(move || {
    |             ^^^^^ `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Header<'a, Body<'a>>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `CreatorPipeline<Header<'a, Body<'a>>, std::sync::Arc<[u8; 16]>, (std::sync::Arc<[u8; 16]>, std::path::PathBuf, u64), (std::vec::Vec<u8>, u64, std::vec::Vec<u8>), Block, Body<'a>>`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Header<'a, Body<'a>>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `(std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Header<'a, Body<'a>>>, std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<Header<'a, Body<'a>>>)`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `CreatorPipeline<Header<'a, Body<'a>>, std::sync::Arc<[u8; 16]>, (std::sync::Arc<[u8; 16]>, std::path::PathBuf, u64), (std::vec::Vec<u8>, u64, std::vec::Vec<u8>), Block, Body<'a>>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `&CreatorPipeline<Header<'a, Body<'a>>, std::sync::Arc<[u8; 16]>, (std::sync::Arc<[u8; 16]>, std::path::PathBuf, u64), (std::vec::Vec<u8>, u64, std::vec::Vec<u8>), Block, Body<'a>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:182:19: 232:14 file:std::path::PathBuf, self:&CreatorPipeline<Header<'a, Body<'a>>, std::sync::Arc<[u8; 16]>, (std::sync::Arc<[u8; 16]>, std::path::PathBuf, u64), (std::vec::Vec<u8>, u64, std::vec::Vec<u8>), Block, Body<'a>>, tx_main:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::sync::Arc<[u8; 16]>>, tx_input:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<(std::sync::Arc<[u8; 16]>, std::path::PathBuf, u64)>, tx_fd:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<(std::vec::Vec<u8>, u64, std::vec::Vec<u8>)>]`
    = note: required by `rayon_core::spawn::spawn`
```

There are 11 more errors like that. All some variation of `Foo cannot be shared between threads safely`. [Here's a gist with all the errors.](https://gist.github.com/Ironlenny/28d5f086617761fc0891fb74c4475ef6)

Here's a snippet of my code:

```rust
...

// File creation pipeline
pub struct CreatorPipeline<A, B, C, D, E, F> {
    magic: Arc<[u8; 8]>,
    rec_set_id: Arc<RwLock<Option<&'static [u8; 16]>>>,
    writes: (Sender<A>, Receiver<A>),           // A: Header<Body>
    main: (Sender<B>, Receiver<B>),             // B: Arc<[u8; 16]>
    input: (Sender<C>, Receiver<C>),            // C: (Arc<[u8; 16]>, File)
    body: (Sender<F>, Receiver<F>),             // F: Body
    file_description: (Sender<D>, Receiver<D>), // D: (Arc<[u8; 16]>, u64, Vec<u8>)
    recovery: (Sender<E>, Receiver<E>),         // E: Block
}



// Creation pipeline methods
impl<'a>
    CreatorPipeline<
        Header<Body<'a>>,          // writes Packet
        Arc<[u8; 16]>,                 // main file_id
        (Arc<[u8; 16]>, PathBuf, u64), // input (file_id, file, length)
        (Vec<u8>, u64, Vec<u8>),       // file_description (name, length, hash_16k)
        Block,                         // recovery Block
        Body<'a>,                      // packet Body
    >
{
    ...

    // First Stage: Create file ids and partial bodies for FileDescription. Send
    // file ids, partial bodies and file readers to the correct channels.
    fn create_file_id(&self, files: Vec<PathBuf>) -> Result<(), ExitFailure> {
        let (tx_main, _) = &self.main; // sender for create_main()
        let (tx_input, _) = &self.input; // sender for create_input()
        let (tx_fd, _) = &self.file_description; // sender for create_fd()

        for file in files {
            let tx_main = tx_main.clone();
            let tx_input = tx_input.clone();
            let tx_fd = tx_fd.clone();

            // Spawn thread
            spawn(move || {
                let mut reader = File::open(&file)
                    .with_context(|_| format!("Could not open file {}", file.display()))
                    .unwrap();

                // Get filename from path
                let name = file
                    .file_stem()
                    .unwrap()
                    .to_string_lossy()
                    .into_owned()
                    .into_bytes();

                let length = {
                    let metadata = metadata(&file).unwrap();
                    metadata.len()
                };

                // Hash first 16k of the file
                let hash_16k = {
                    let mut hasher_16k = Md5::new();
                    let mut buffer = [0; 16384];
                    reader.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
                    for byte in buffer.iter() {
                        hasher_16k.input([byte.clone()]);
                    }

                    let result = hasher_16k.result();
                    let hash_16k = result.as_slice().to_owned();
                    hash_16k
                };

                // Generate File ID
                let file_id = {
                    let mut hasher_file_id = Md5::new();
                    hasher_file_id.input(&hash_16k);
                    hasher_file_id.input(&length.to_le_bytes());
                    hasher_file_id.input(&name);
                    let file_id = hasher_file_id.result().to_vec();
                    let file_id = self.convert_to_byte_array(file_id);
                    Arc::new(file_id) // Problem line
                };

                // Partial FileDescription (name, length, hash_16k)
                let partial_body = (name, length, hash_16k);

                // sender for channels
                tx_main.send(Arc::clone(&file_id)).unwrap();
                tx_input.send((Arc::clone(&file_id), file, length)).unwrap();
                tx_fd.send(partial_body).unwrap();
            });
        }

        Ok(())
    }

    ...
}
```

[Here's the full source.](https://gist.github.com/Ironlenny/b9c8e1dc13b21e048146d446e2e6de8e)
[Arc Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html)
[Rayon Documentation](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.3/rayon/index.html)

Edit: Forgot to mention that I'm using 2018 edition stable.

Comment: Is it maybe because of the lifetime? You can only pass `'static` lifetimes to threads. Also what is the point in having `Arc<&'a [u8; 8]>`? Why not `Arc<[u8; 8]>`?

Comment: [`Vec<u8>` implements `Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html?search=slice#synthetic-implementations) so it can be put in an `Arc` and shared between threads. `array`s can't because they don't implement `Send`.

Comment: Ok, how is [UUID](https://docs.rs/uuid/0.7.4/uuid/struct.Uuid.html#impl-Send) getting the *Send* & *Sync* auto-impl? Which is just a wrapper over `[u8; 16]`.

Comment: @chpio Good point. Actually, it looks like `u8` arrays [do implement `Send`](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1483e7d22da9c060c60f083c7f480be7) even though the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html) don't mention it…

Comment: Maybe it's not showing up in the docs, because of the *Send* & *Sync* traits being auto traits, so they do not show up for generic types?

Comment: @chpio But `Vec` is a generic type and `Send` shows up [there](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html?search=slice#synthetic-implementations). It also shows up for [primitive types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.u8.html#impl-Send). Maybe the issue is that `array` is _both_ generic and primitive?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one stumped.

Comment: @chpio In retrospect I don't need the Arc<&'a [u8; 8]>. I'm still learning Rust.

Comment: @Ironlenny ah, yeah sorry for that, i thought it's causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help from the Rust Discord server. Turns out that `let file_id = self.convert_to_byte_array(file_id);` was the problem line. Which makes sense, I'm trying to move `self` into multiple threads, which obviously doesn't work. I just wish the compiler errors was more helpful.